# Python Selenium Path not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have wrote the code

```
import os
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.page_load_strategy = 'eager'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
url = "https://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/chemicals/tatachemicals/TC"
driver.get(url)
try:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
except Exception:
driver.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL +'Escape')
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Bonus").click()
try:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
except Exception:
    driver.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL +'Escape')
for i in range(0, 50):
    bonus_month = driver.find_element_by_xpath ("//*[@class= 'mctable1.thborder.frtab']/tbody/tr[%s]/td[1]"%(i)) 
    print(bonus_month.text)
    bonus = driver.find_element_by_xpath ("//*[@class= 'mctable1.thborder.frtab']/tbody/tr[%s]/td[1]"%(i)) 
    print(bonus.text)
```

This gives me error

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@class= 'mctable1.thborder.frtab']/tbody/tr[0]/td[1]"}
```

Element on the page:
[image]

Where I am making mistake in finding Exbonus and Ratio?

Comment: bonus_month - which element on page is it?

Comment: There is error because this element cannot be found

Comment: but I have added driver.find_element_by_link_text("Bonus").click() to click on Bonus link and page is opening ahead but not selecting the data.

Comment: Does it make a click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use the clickable method from the `expected conditions` to check that the element is clickable within given time to just make sure it is operational.

Once the click action performed on the bonus link the table takes some time to finishes loading. In meantime selenium tries to fetch the table content and fails to get it. So again add wait for the element to load and then grab the table using Xpath and iterate over the rows of the table. -

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@id='corporation_tab']//a[@href='#ca_bonus']")))

driver.find_element_by_link_text("Bonus").click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//tbody[@id='id_b']/tr")))

tableRows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody[@id="id_b"]/tr')
print(tableRows)
for i in tableRows:
    AnnouncementDate = i.find_element_by_xpath('td[1]').text
    exbonus = i.find_element_by_xpath('td[2]').text
    ratio = i.find_element_by_xpath('td[3]').text

    print(AnnouncementDate + " \t\t " + exbonus + " \t\t " + ratio)
```

This returns me the output -

[image]

You will need following extra import -

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks, already reached to this point but how can we separate dates and bonus?

Comment: @sam Updated the answer as per you requirement. It was easy though.

Answer (score 1):

This partially will solve your issue with locators:

1 To find Ex-Bonus use `css` selector: `#id_b>tr>td:nth-of-type(2)`

2 To find ratio use also `css` selector, `#id_b>tr>td:nth-of-type(3)`

To iterante use:

```
#id_b>tr:nth-of-type(x)>td:nth-of-type(3)
```

where `x` is the number of row.
For example, `#id_b>tr:nth-of-type(1)>td:nth-of-type(3)` will give you text with ratio **3:5**

[image]

If you avoid avoid using #id_b, this locator will not be unique.
Instead of range function I'd use find_elements_by_css_selector. Try following:

```
rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#id_b>tr")
for row in rows:
    bonus = row.find_element_by_css_selector("td:nth-of-type(2)").text
    ratio = row.find_element_by_css_selector("td:nth-of-type(3)").text
```

There are only 5 of this elements on the page. I'll have to click `See More`.

Comment: This bonus and ratio prints nothing but blank lines.

Comment: row.text gives "19 Jun, 1995 04 Oct, 1995 3:5" but bonus and ratio print blank

Comment: Try changing rows locatot to `#id_b>tr>` It means direct child of element

Comment: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Comment: why we cant locate using table class and  then tr td?

Comment: You can try any locators you like more, it is just a matter of taste. For example, xpaths are also possible, but they will be longer.

Comment: AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'driver'

Comment: Yes, I removed this part, check again

Comment: Yes I removed that too and still getting empty list now []

Comment: Interesting. Try `get_attribute("textContent")` or `get_attribute("innerText")` or `get_attribute("value")`

Comment: yes seems interesting it also didnt worked and for me table id also didn't worked

Comment: Try replacing td:nth-of-type(2) with td:nth-child(2)

Comment: Also, put a bigger wait before this table is loaded

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231269/discussion-between-vitaliis-and-sam).